# Rotating an image around a pivot point

Tags: android

The issue is simple: I want to rotate an image around a certain pivot point. Here is the code I use:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setTranslate(bmpWidth/2, 0);
matrix.preRotate(degrees, bmpWidth/2, 0);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    bitmap, 0, 0, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, matrix, true);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bell);
imageView.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

I get the rotation degrees from the accelerometer sensor. The result is that every time the image is rotated around its center point.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Matrix transformations, but you might get different results from changing the transform order, for example, using `postRotate()` or `setRotate()`.

Comment: could you give me an example that works? because I've tried to use those methods, but I had no luck. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used Matrix transforms so I can't give you an example, but I think I have read about problems where the transforms gave unexpected results if not applied in the right order. Does it work if you try using *just* `postRotate()` without the `setTranslate()`?

Answer (score 10):

I think you should try doing this:

```
imageView.setPivotX(desiredXPivotPoint);
imageView.setPivotY(desiredYPivotPoint);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This is only API 11 and above, and it doesn't seem to do anything anyway!

Answer (score -1):

This is kinda old, but there is a function that allows you to specify both the degrees of rotation as well as the pivot point:

```
    imageView.setRotation(degrees, px, py)
```

Comment: There is no such function in Android. At least, now.